# $Y_n = \sup_{k \geq n} E(X_k | F_n)$ is a martingale if $X_n$ is $L^1$ bounded non-negative submartingale

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_n$ be a $L^1$ bounded non-negative submartingale. Let $Y_n = \sup_{k \geq n} E(X_k | F_n)$. Show that

(1) $Y_n$ is a martingale

(2) $X_n \leq Y_n$ for all $n$ a.s.

(3) $\sup \|X_n\|_1 = \sup \|Y_n\|_1$

(4) If $T_n$ is an $F_n$ martingale st $X_n \leq T_n$ a.s. then $Y_n \leq T_n$ a.s.

Comment: I have been stuck on part (1) already.

(2) seems quite obvious because we can take $k = n$. I'm not sure how to do (3) and (4).

Does anyone have idea how to solve (1),(3),(4) ? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is (3) saying?  How are $\|X\|_1$ and $\|Y\|_1$ defined?

Comment: $\| X\|_1 = \sup \|X_n\|_1$

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the tower property to show that for any $k \ge n$, we have
$$E[X_{k+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \ge E[X_k \mid \mathcal{F}_n].$$
So we may rewrite $Y_n$ as $$Y_n = \lim_{k \to \infty} E[X_k \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \tag{*}$$ since the limit of an increasing sequence equals its supremum.  Now $E[Y_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = Y_n$ follows from the conditional monotone convergence theorem, proving (1).

(2) is immediate as you said.

For (3), note that it is sufficient to show $E Y_0 = \sup_n E X_n$.  Use (*) and the monotone convergence theorem.

Hint for (4): For any $k \ge n$ we have $E[X_k \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \le E[T_k \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$.

Comment: Nice observation for (*)! Thanks! I believe $X_n$ actually converges to $X_{\infty}$, so it's not necessary to use the monotone convergence theorems?

Comment: Also, for (4), $E[X_k | F_n]$  converges to $E[X_{\infty}|F_n] = Y_n$. Although $E[T_k | F_n] = T_n$, $T_k$ doesn't necessarily converge. It is still okay to say $Y_n \leq T_n$?

Comment: @user207952: If you want to invoke the martingale convergence theorem to get that $X_n \to X_\infty$ a.s. and in $L^1$, you can simplify a few steps, yes.  But you don't need it.  For 4, for any fixed $n,k$ with $k \ge n$, since $E[T_k \mid \mathcal{F}_n] = T_n$ we have $E[X_k \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \le T_n$ almost surely.  Now pass to the limit as $k \to \infty$, keeping $n$ fixed.  We don't need to assume anything about the convergence of $T_n$.

Comment: @user207952 Maybe you want to try "@Nate" in order to get an answer.

Comment: @DavMat: The author of a question or answer automatically gets pinged for comments on that post, so the @ is not needed (and in some cases the system will refuse to include it since it is redundant).  I looked at the other question but I don't have any suggestions at present.

Comment: Hi Nate. I added a hint I got for that question. But at present I'm not sure how to apply that hint. Could you take a look? Thanks.